# Assertion python

Tags: python, recursion

i have problem with recursion in python. My code looks like:

```
counter = 0
result = []
def count_inversion(sequence):
    global result, counter
    """
        Count inversions in a sequence of numbers
    """
    sequence = list(sequence)
    if len(sequence) == 1:
        result.append(sequence[0])
        if result == sorted(result):
            result = []
            return counter
        else:
            sequence = result
            result = []
            return count_inversion(sequence)

    if sequence[0] > sequence[1]:
        result.append(sequence.pop(1))
        counter += 1
        return count_inversion(sequence)
    else:
        result.append(sequence[0])
        return count_inversion(sequence[1:])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
    assert count_inversion((1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 7, 6)) == 3, "Example"
    assert count_inversion((0, 1, 2, 3)) == 0, "Sorted"
    assert count_inversion((99, -99)) == 1, "Two numbers"
    assert count_inversion((5, 3, 2, 1, 0)) == 10, "Reversed"
```

When I run asserts individually it works fine, but when i want to run it all together I have problem that variable count has still the value from previous assert (in this case 3 from first asser). I dont know where to put counter = 0 in my code to work it properly. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try after each assert?

Comment: That's why you shouldn't use global variables. Pass them as parameters instead.

Comment: I cannot modify parameters in this function, it should be only one (sequence).

Comment: @Daniel: Then define a sub-function inside your `count_inversion` function to do the work, and move the global variables inside `count_inversion`.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

Option 1: Initialize in the method:

```
def count_inversion(sequence):
    counter = 0
    result = []
    # Your code
```

Option 2: As Rawing suggested you could use parameters:

```
def count_inversion(sequence, counter, result):
    #your code
```

You can than call it like:

```
count_inversion((1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 7, 6), 0, []):
```

A cleaner way would be:

```
def count_inversion(sequence, counter=0, result=[]):
    #your code
```

This way you only have to asign those parameters if you want them to be something else:

count_inversion((1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 7, 6), counter=1):  # Counter will now start with 1

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your issue, I removed counter as global variable and passed it each time to the function `count_inversion`... another solution which is **NOT RECOMMENDED** is to set a new variable = `counter` before your `return` then set back `counter=0`, then return that new variable

```
result = []
def count_inversion(sequence, counter):
    global result
    """
       Count inversions in a sequence of numbers
    """
    sequence = list(sequence, counter)
    if len(sequence) == 1:
        result.append(sequence[0])
        if result == sorted(result):
           result = []
           return counter
        else:
           sequence = result
           result = []
           return count_inversion(sequence, counter)

    if sequence[0] > sequence[1]:
        result.append(sequence.pop(1))
        counter += 1
        return count_inversion(sequence, counter)
    else:
        result.append(sequence[0])
        return count_inversion(sequence[1:], counter)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
    assert count_inversion((1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 7, 6),0) == 3, "Example"
    assert count_inversion((0, 1, 2, 3),0) == 0, "Sorted"
    assert count_inversion((99, -99),0) == 1, "Two numbers"
    assert count_inversion((5, 3, 2, 1, 0),0) == 10, "Reversed"
```

based on your comment above, I added the code to keep counter as global:

```
counter=0
result = []
def count_inversion(sequence):
    global result
    global counter
    """
       Count inversions in a sequence of numbers
    """
    sequence = list(sequence)
    if len(sequence) == 1:
        result.append(sequence[0])
        if result == sorted(result):
           result = []
           return_counter=counter
           counter=0
           return return_counter
        else:
           sequence = result
           result = []
           return count_inversion(sequence)

    if sequence[0] > sequence[1]:
        result.append(sequence.pop(1))
        counter += 1
        return count_inversion(sequence)
    else:
        result.append(sequence[0])
        return count_inversion(sequence[1:])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
    assert count_inversion((1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 7, 6)) == 3, "Example"
    assert count_inversion((0, 1, 2, 3)) == 0, "Sorted"
    assert count_inversion((99, -99)) == 1, "Two numbers"
    assert count_inversion((5, 3, 2, 1, 0)) == 10, "Reversed"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of your function that doesn't mess up with the globals:

```
def count_inversion(sequence, current=(), counter=0):
    """Count inversions in a sequence of numbers."""
    if len(sequence) < 2:
        current += sequence
        if list(current) == sorted(current):
            return counter
        return count_inversion(current, (), counter)
    index = sequence[0] > sequence[1]
    return count_inversion(sequence[:index] + sequence[index+1:],
                           current + sequence[index:index+1],
                           counter + index)
```

The main differences are:

- it uses default arguments to track `current` and `counter`
- it uses directly tuples so that list conversion is not needed
- it factorizes the recursive call, by using an index (`0` or `1`) to pop the element from

Output:

```
>>> count_inversion((1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 7, 6))
3
>>> count_inversion((0, 1, 2, 3))
0
>>> count_inversion((99, -99))
1
>>> count_inversion((5, 3, 2, 1, 0))
10
```